# PHP converter quilômetros/horas por Milhas náuticas / horas

Tags: php

Galera como converto um valor Km/h em milhas náuticas ?

Exemplo: tenho um valor de 49km/h preciso converter esse valor para milhas náuticas hora "Mn/h" alguém sabe como fazer essa função para converter procurei no site do php mais não achei

Comment: 49*0,539957= 26,4578  Pode checar aqui http://extraconversion.com/pt/comprimento/metros/metros-para-milhas-nauticas.html

Comment: $strKm=49; $strConversor=0.539957; $strConvertido=$strKm*$strConversor; echo $strConvertido;

Comment: No caso nao metros e sim velocidade que estou querendo e a mesma coisa ?

Comment: O que está acima são variáveis PHP para vc poder trabalhar com PHP. As unidades de medidas ficam subentendidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que 1 [milha náutica](http://convertlive.com/pt/u/converter/milhas-n%C3%A1uticas/em/metros#1) equivale a **1,852 kilômetro**, para converter *Km/h* em *mn/h* basta o seguinte cálculo:

Dividir o valor em *Km* por **1.852**:

```
<?php
function kmh_to_mnh($v){

   $mnH = $v / 1.852;

   return $mnH.'mn/h';
}

echo kmh_to_mnh(50); // 50Km/h -> 26.99784017278mn/h
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, não seria apenas multiplicar o valor por 0.5396118?

Comment: Só isso ? vou tentar ja digo aqui se deu certo!